# Lower one value by a ratio in a formula

Tags: r, rate

I have a value `d` at maximum height `h_max`. This value should at each interval decrease by specific `ratio`. Let's say:

```
d = 10
ratio = 1/100 # or 1:100 outside R
```

So, at intervals

```
h = 100*c(1:h_max)
```

my d_h should be:

```
d_h = c(10:1)
```

**How to predict the `d_h` values given `d`, `h_max` and ratio (rate) values?**

Working example:

```
h_max = 1000  # in cm
ratio = 1/67
```

What are my `d_h` at intervals `h`? I expect the range 10 to 0.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are exactly aiming at, but I guess you are looking for a linear function, i.e.,

```
h_max = 1000
ratio = 1/67
f <- function(h) -ratio*h + h_max
```

then you can get `d_h` via calling `f(h)` for any given `h`

Comment: This sound very promising but when I run it I get very small differences between values?  Here is more of the question background, maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60164517/calculate-diameters-at-specific-heights-based-on-taper-ratio) would help to explain my question better? I have completed my question as well.

Comment: @maycca you get small value since you did not use the same units for input and output. I added an answer to the link you pasted, so please check it out